# Is it bad practice to use LESS compiler in Wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, less

I'm developing a Wordpress theme that offers the ability to change site's color from the Theme panel. My idea is :

1. Admin select some colors from the Theme panel, then click save button.
2. After color options are saved, use [lessphp](https://github.com/leafo/lessphp)! class to recompile the style.less file to style.css file.

But I wonder is this good or bad practice ? Because in order to do it, the style.css file must be writable (chmod 666 ?), and I read somewhere that with that permission, others on the same server can overwrite that file, and add bad script to it.

I know another way to do the color changing, is output the changed color right from the  tag of the page. But with many color to change, I think this way is inconvenience.
So, what do you think about my idea ? If it's bad practice, is there any way to do the color changing ?

Comment: There's a [WordPress Answers](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) sister site, where your question might get more attention.

Comment: If lessphp is executed through a web server only the apache (or whatever) user needs to have write permitions on your css files. If i remember correctly wordpress allows you to edit your template php files from its back end, what you are describing matches theyr approach.

Comment: @StefanDenchev : my bad, I always visit stackoverflow first when I have trouble, so I forgot that site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be writable only by server 655 or by group 665 you don't have to allow anybody to write this file.

Secondly: if there are others on web server then you have security issues and changing style.css is your least problem.

Anyway this shouldn't be a seen as a bad practice - just the design of an extension.

Comment: Thank you, so if the website is on a shared hosting service, how should I chmod style.css to fix the security issue ?

Comment: That depends on the used hosting, but i think that if you have FTP access (great will be Filezilla) you can change access rights by FTP client (Filezilla can do this). On shared hosting it's hosting firm responsibility that other users shouldn't be able to access your data - so it will be protected.

Answer (score 1):

No it's not a bad practice as long as you set permissions to edit files in the back-end. Since this is going to be an activity by the admins on the back-end it should not effect the performance of front-end template.

Answer (score 0):

If it happens server side, nothing wrong with it. If you were using a client side compiler, I'd be concerned about a JS failure breaking your site.

This could also introduce latency to your site. You might want to look into using a cacheing plugin like QuickCache to pre-compile your site for better performance: http://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-cache/